# Hystrix Dashboard not available with Jersey endpoint

Tags: jersey, hystrix

I have a Spring Boot application with a public endpoint implemented with Jersey/JAX-RS annotations.
Hystrix Dashboard is enabled with @EnableHystrixDashboard, HystrixMetricsStreamServlet is registered under "/hystrix.stream" (as in the examples out there).

When accessing .../hystrix.stream the metrics data is available for the HystrixCommands but **the starter dashboard page "/hystrix" is empty** giving **HTTP 404 status code**.

Any idea why it is not accessible with Jersey?

If the same is implemented with Spring WebMVC (not Jersey) the dashboard page is available.

My **pom.xml**

- excludes spring-webmvc and depends on jersey
- depends on hystrix, event-stream, dashboard, actuator

-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hystrix.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>hystrix-metrics-event-stream</artifactId>
    <version>${hystrix.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.archaius</groupId>
    <artifactId>archaius-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```